# Problem sending a post graphql, nextjs react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql

Hello guys I have the following problem:

wherever I try to post a comment I get the following error:

```
ClientError: input:3: Field "post" is not defined by type CommentCreateInput.
: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"input:3: Field \"post\" is not defined by type CommentCreateInput.\n"}],"data":null,"extensions":{"requestId":"cl3uwxntaa8r70cll4db25q72"},"status":400,"headers":{}},"request":{"query":"\n    mutation CreateComment($name: String!, $email: String!, $comment: String!, $slug: String!) {\n      createComment(data: {name: $name, email: $email, comment: $comment, post: {connect: {slug: $slug}}}) { id }\n    }\n  ","variables":{"name":"Roberto","email":"robert.rivera@outlook.com","comment":"a","slug":"react-testing"}}}
    at /home/xue/Documents/Programacion/blog-nodejs/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:356:31
    at step (/home/xue/Documents/Programacion/blog-nodejs/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:63:23)
    at Object.next (/home/xue/Documents/Programacion/blog-nodejs/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:44:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/xue/Documents/Programacion/blog-nodejs/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:35:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  response: {
    
}
API resolved without sending a response for /api/comments, this may result in stalled requests.
```

this is my code so far:

pages/api/comments.js
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from 'graphql-request';

```
const graphqlAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT
const graphcmsToken = process.env.XUE_TOKEN


// export a default function for API route to work
export default async function asynchandler(req, res) {
  console.log({graphcmsToken})
  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient((graphqlAPI), {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${graphcmsToken}`,
    },
  })
  const query = gql`
    mutation CreateComment($name: String!, $email: String!, $comment: String!, $slug: String!) {
      createComment(data: {name: $name, email: $email, comment: $comment, post: {connect: {slug: $slug}}}) { id }
    }
  `
    try {
      const result = await graphQLClient.request(query, req.body)
      return res.status(200).send(result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }


}
```

-- this my commentform.jsx
components/commentForm.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { submitComment } from '../services';

const CommentsForm = ({ slug }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [localStorage, setLocalStorage] = useState(null);
  const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ name: null, email: null, comment: null, storeData: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage(window.localStorage);
    const initalFormData = {
      name: window.localStorage.getItem('name'),
      email: window.localStorage.getItem('email'),
      storeData: window.localStorage.getItem('name') || window.localStorage.getItem('email'),
    };
    setFormData(initalFormData);
  }, []);

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    const { target } = e;
    if (target.type === 'checkbox') {
      setFormData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [target.name]: target.checked,
      }));
    } else {
      setFormData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [target.name]: target.value,
      }));
    }
  };

  const handlePostSubmission = () => {
    setError(false);
    const { name, email, comment, storeData } = formData;
    if (!name || !email || !comment) {
      setError(true);
      return;
    }
    const commentObj = {
      name,
      email,
      comment,
      slug,
    };

    if (storeData) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('name', name);
      window.localStorage.setItem('email', email);
    } else {
      window.localStorage.removeItem('name');
      window.localStorage.removeItem('email');
    }

    submitComment(commentObj)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.createComment) {
          if (!storeData) {
            formData.name = '';
            formData.email = '';
          }
          formData.comment = '';
          setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            ...formData,
          }));
          setShowSuccessMessage(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setShowSuccessMessage(false);
          }, 3000);
        }
      });
  };

  return (
    
  );
};

export default CommentsForm;
```

I don't know how to get this working and sorry for my bad english. Let me know if you need more info

edit:
this is my schema I don't know if im missing something

```
import { request, gql } from 'graphql-request';

const graphqlAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT;

export const getPosts = async () => {
    const query = gql`
      query MyQuery {
        postsConnection {
          edges {
            cursor
            node {
              author {
                bio
                name
                id
                photo {
                  url
                }
              }
              createdAt
              slug
              title
              excerpt
              featuredImage {
                url
              }
              categories {
                name
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;
    

    const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);

    return result.postsConnection.edges;
}

export const getRecentPosts = async () => {
    const query = gql`
      query getPostDetails() {
        posts(
          orderBy: createdAt_ASC
          last: 3
        ) {
          title
          featuredImage {
            url
          }
          createdAt
          slug
        }
      }
    `;
    

    const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query);

    return result.posts;
}

export const getSimilarPosts = async ( categories, slug ) => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetPostDetails($slug: String!, $categories: [String!]) {
      posts(
        where: { slug_not: $slug, AND: { categories_some: {slug_in: $categories} } }
        last: 3
      ) {
        title
        featuredImage {
          url
        }
        createdAt
        slug
      }
    }
  `
  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query, { categories, slug });
  return result.posts
}

export const getCategories = async () => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetCategories {
      categories {
        name
        slug
      }
    }
  `
  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query)
  return result.categories
}

export const getPostDetails = async (slug) => {
  const query = gql`
    query GetPostDetails($slug : String!) {
      post(where: {slug: $slug}) {
        title
        excerpt
        featuredImage {
          url
        }
        author{
          name
          bio
          photo {
            url
          }
        }
        createdAt
        slug
        content {
          raw
        }
        categories {
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query, { slug })

  return result.post
}

export const submitComment = async (obj) => {
  const result = await fetch('/api/comments', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
  })

  return result.json()
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "*Field `"post"` is not defined by type `CommentCreateInput`*". You need to change either your schema or your query. We can't tell which one you want, and you haven't shown us your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using graphcms. Go to the graphcms dashboard and set up a relationship between the Post and Comment identities.

If you check well in the Schema>Post section at the end there should be a relationship with the comment entity.

graphCMS is complaining that you are trying to assign a comment to a post; when the "Post" entity has no reference to "Comment"

The Relation in graphCMS is called a Reference. From the "Post" entity assign a reference to "Comment"